# Is it possible to iterate over a list of lists and print out the name of the lists in addition to their contents?

Tags: python, list, iteration, nested-lists

I am trying to print out out the ticker symbol next to its two respective values within my nested list.

```
gme_infos = [45.95, 133.46]        # Number of shares, Cost basis
amc_infos = [49, 32.24]            # Number of shares, Cost basis
list_infos = [gme_infos,amc_infos]

for i in list_infos
     print(i)
```

My output so far is what you would expect

```
[45.95, 133.46]
[49, 32.24]
```

What can I do to have my printed values appear next to the list they stem from but as part of iterating?

ex

```
gme_infos [45.95, 133.46]
amc_infos [49, 32.24]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `list_infos` a dict, not a list.

```
list_infos = {'gme_infos': gme_infos, 'amc_infos': amc_infos}
for name, infos in list_infos.items():
    print(f"{name} {infos}")
```